# How to make UIBarButtonItem behave consistently for light and firm touches in iOS 8.4, using Xcode 7.2/iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

This question has been changed due to ongoing debugging. Initially the indicators were that it was iOS8.4x vs iOS9.2 on the target issue. Upon more debugging I now believe may be an issue about touch sensitivity.

I have a refresh button in UIToolBar that I disable and grey-out while refreshing as a signifier for a somewhat long refresh operation. 
The code below:

- was built using Xcode 7.2/iOS 9.2
- works on iOS 9.x simulators for iPad2 and iPhone 5.
- does not work (the button works, executes refresh logic but does not    grey out during operation) on iOS8.x iPad2 and iPhone5 devices. *However it works on iPhone4 iOS 8.4 devices if the button is pressed for at least 2 seconds*. On a  fleeting touch the method executes, but the disable action and its visual effect (grey out) do not happen.
- Hypothesis: It works a simulator since it simulates a touch event through mouse clicks.

## Image below shows the correct behavior during refresh on iOS9.2 simulator

[image: While refreshing on 9.2 simulator, correct behavior]

### Image below shows that refresh button is not greyed out during refresh on iOS 8.4 device when touched for < 1s. The target method executes, but its disable action has no effect.

[image: While refreshing on 8.4 device, refreshed button not greyed out]

As a side-note, the iPhone5 does not have SIM but is on WiFi and network functionality of the app is correct.

Do I need to do something different so that a disabled button greys-out in iOS8.x independent of touch duration? In the code, I have comments about what I have tried and did not work. Speculation: Is it possible that some artifacts of 3D touch in iOS9.2 SDK have slipped into the application binary and making it misbehave on 8.4x phone target?

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let refreshButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"refresh"),landscapeImagePhone: UIImage(named:"refresh"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    //..other buttons.

   //..... Other code that has nothing to do with refreshButton

   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       refreshButton.addTargetForAction(self, action: "performRefresh:")
       let space1 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
       buttonArray = [someButton, space1, refreshButton] // There are more buttons.
       self.setToolbarItems(buttonArray, animated: false)
   } //viewWillAppear
   func performRefresh(sender: UIButton) {
        NSLog("************Refresh Requested")
        //sender.enabled = false //compiles,  OK iOS 9, but does not grey out button  on iOS8 
        //sender.anyFunction()  // Results in exception stating that sender does not know that message.
        //Switching to self.refreshButton instead.
        self.refreshButton.enabled = false // OK iOS 9, but does not grey out button  on iOS8 
        //self.refreshButton.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor // has not effect in either OS
        //self.refreshButton.alpha or self.refreshButton.setNeedsDisplay() are not present.

       //Refresh Logic


       NSLog("************Refresh Done")
       self.refreshButton.enabled = true
       //I had the reciprocal operations (restore tint, set alpha to 1.0 here while debugging)
   } //performRefresh
} // myViewController
```

Comment: As a piece of advice, it might be helpful to include screenshots.

Comment: @SevenBits Added the images

Answer (score 1):

I might not be understanding your question so well but maybe you can just change the buttons tint color when its disabled `self.refreshButton.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];` and then change the color back when its done.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but I have already tried this (mentioned in the comments in the code), bit the tintColor setting has no effect either in iOS 8.x device or iOS9.X simulator. Thanks for the comment though.